# В чем суть IDLE (Python)?

Tags: python, idle

Скачала, установила Python 3.8.

Потом узнала, что есть IDLE.

См разные иконки приложения
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В чем идея? Почему, когда я набираю одну и ту же команду в разных окнах, в IDLE она работает, а Python на черном фоне (даже не знаю, как это назвать) - не работает.
По скринам, надеюсь, поймете.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Т.е. изучать удобнее в IDLE? А в чем смысл тогда того приложения на черном фоне? В чем их разница? И почему там выдает ошибку?

Comment: потому что idle это что то вроде встроенного тектового редактора для python, а то, что на черном фоне это консоль с открытым интерпретатором Python(исполняет команду одну за одной по мере ввода команда)

Comment: и зачем тогда она? Т.е. как вы принимаете решения, что сегодня вам надо работать в этой консоли, а завтра в IDLE?

Comment: ну для начала я читаю книжку (что то вроде укуса питона, например) и узнаю от туда, что интерактивная оболочка пригодна только для теста какой то ерунды, т.е она есть и на том спасибо, в основном ее никто не трогает. А в редакторе я пишу код своей программы :) в книжках подробно все расписано :)

Comment: В белом окошке вы написали программу целиком и запустили её. То белое окошко, где вывелось 1 2 3 6.0 - аналог чёрной консоли. Но в белой консоли есть несколько удобств, например можно кликать правой кнопкой мыши

Comment: Если интересно, из-за чего возникла ошибка - интерпретатор ждал ввод числа после a=float(input()), но получил вместо числа строку: b=float(input()). Поэтому заругался

Comment: Очень приятно, что вы пытаетесь разобраться. Но как было сказано ранее необходимы начальные теоретические данные о Python. Книги бы вам очень помогли.

Comment: @Дмитрий, Я не по книгам начала учить, а по видео лекциям+статьям из интернета. Там изучаю правила. Нашла сайт, как установить. Установила. Как раз интерпретатор. Там слова не было про IDEL. Только потом нашла про IDEL. К самим правилам набора программ пока вопросов не было. В принципе, я ответ на свой вопрос поняла, мне на него ответили. Спасибо.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
И почему там выдает ошибку?
```

Прежде всего просьба - никогда не прилагайте скриншоты. Всегда - только **текст**. Текст программы, текст сообщения об ошибке и т.д. Это позволит легко цитировать, искать в инете и т.д.

По сути. Что такое интерпретатор (любой)? Это программа, которая ввела Вашу команду - тут же её исполнила. После чего ждёт ввода следующей. Теперь смотрим, что Вы делали "в чёрном окне".  Вы ввели команду языка Python:

```
a = float(input))
```

и нажали клавишу Enter. Интерпретатор Python попытался эту команду. **тут же** (!) исполнить. Для того, что бы её исполнить, ему нужно ввести с клавиатуры строку, содержащую символьное представление числа и преобразовать её в число с плавающей точкой.

Интерпретатор ждёт, что вы введёте эту строку - запись числа. Но вместо этого Вы вводи строку, содержащую "b = float(input))". Интерпретатор не понимает, как преобразовать эту строку в число и говорит Вам об этом:

```
Value error: could  not convert string to...
```

Если бы Вы ввели нечто вроде "2.17" - интепретаор ввёл бы строку, преобразовал её в число и запомнил в переменной *a*. А уж после этого можно было бы вводить следующую команду: "b = float(input))".

В этом и заключается принципиальная разница между компилятором и интерпретатором: Для компилятора Вы сначала вводите **всю** программу, а потом запускаете её на выполнение, а интерпретатор пытается выполнить каждую введённую строку программы сразу.

Почему всё работает в Idle? Потому, что в этой IDE есть специальное окно **редактора** и есть специальное окно **выполнения**. И там Вы сначала ввели всю программу, а потом уже запустили её на выполнение. Но выполнял Вашу программу всё равно, тот самый интерпретатор с чёрным окном. Просто IDE это окно спрятала от Вас.

Comment: *>>Python >>компилятор* - исправьте, пожалуйста.

Comment: `Что такое интерпретатор (любой)? Это программа, которая ввела Вашу команду - тут же её исполнила.` - нет. Современные интерпретаторы парсят программу полностью (не по одной "команде" за раз), переводят в байт-код, потом его исполняют (интерпретируют). В данном случае в "черном окне" REPL (read-eval-print loop) - интерактивная "оболочка", которая как раз выполняет по одной команде за раз (прочитал одну команду, выполнил, напечатал, повторил).

Comment: @МихаилМуругов "исправьте, пожалуйста" - не понял - что исправить? Или Вы считаете, что программа, котрая запускается, когда я в команднойй строке ввожу *python* является компилятором?

Comment: @insolor "Современные интерпретаторы парсят программу полностью" - хотите я прямо сейчас сделаю видео, на котором интерпретатор питона будет вводить и **выполнять** мои команды по одной строке? :-) И пришлю Вам...

*в "черном окне" REPL (read-eval-print loop) - интерактивная "оболочка"*  это не оболочка. Это и есть **интерпретатор** питона. А то, что современные run-time системы умеют компилировать языки интерепретаторов, я знаю. Но рассказывать TS про это - просто морочить голову человеку, который только-только начал въезжать в тему.   Вопрос был конкретный. И ответ был дан **конкретный**.

Comment: @Sergey Python - интерпретируемый язык. Понятие компиляции к нему не применимо.

Comment: "это не оболочка" - да, неправильно выразился, не оболочка, а режим работы интерпретатора. В целом вы правы, не вижу смысла тут спорить. Я бы сформулировал по-другому, но это ваш ответ, а не мой)

Comment: @МихаилМуругов "Python - интерпретируемый язык." - так я же именно это и написал. 8-0 Я чего то не понимаю?

Comment: @  Sergey, спасибо за ответ. Я действительно только начала изучать Python. На лекциях, что я смотрю, объясняют именно то, как писать программы, как понимать и использовать функции и т.д. Я тут же пробую это делать. А вот где и как - вызвало в итоге вопросы. Вы немного прояснили, спасибо. В итоге пока буду разбираться в IDEL.